# Scope of closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function f1(){
    var x = 5;    
    this.f2 = function(){
        var y = 10; 
        function helper(){
            //Do we have x here because of closure as we have y
        }
        setInterval(helper,100);
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I am doing `new f1()` to create an object. As I understood, `helper` will have access to `y` by closure but I observed that `x` is also available inside `helper` . Can any one explain to me why is this and till what level does closure works in JavaScript.

Comment: var x is an instance variable of class f1 in javascript, so it shall be available thorughout the definition of f1 i-e in all methods of f1.

Comment: Not quite furqan, it is only available to functions defined within the scope of the constructor function. Methods added later, or methods accessed through the prototype, will not have access to x.

Comment: you also have a slight syntax error, it should be `this.f2 = function(){` without the first set of ()

Answer (score 0):

Every variable you define will be visible on the whole function scope. If you want x not to be visible on the helper function I recommend using another approach:

```
var f1 = function () {
  var x = 5; //private variable within f1 scope
}

f1.prototype.f2 = function(){
  var y = 10; // private variable within f2 scope
  function helper(){
    // x is no longer available here
    setInterval(helper,100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closures are created due to scoping rules in JavaScript of functions. I would
say the core tenant of closures is that they maintain state event after
execution till the next time execution returns back to some code path nested
inside of itself.

I think the thing that has tripped you up is that this can go many levels
deep. Or to put it in another way, you do not restrict the scope of a function
by nesting another function inside of it.

x is a variable that is defined within the scope of f1. You then define
this.f2 to an anonymous function, whose scope is still inside of f1. That
means that the anonymous function has access to x just like it has access to
y. Just as helper has access to y. This is what I mean by it nesting downward.

@masylum perfectly outlines how to separate them: Don't define x within the
same function as you define f2.

The one caveat to all of this: "this" can change and it won't follow the same
pattern outlined. "this", or the context object, is apart of the current function that
you are in. So "this" for f1 will be different than "this" inside of
helper. Now it will be the same for the anonymous function that you assigned
to f2 because you assigned it to the context of f1's "this" (ala this.f2 =
).

That being said, you can solve that problem with by using closures. You assign
"this" to a new variable and then you can use that variable in "this"'s place. For example:

```
  function f3() {
    this.isDone = false;
    var that = this;
    function helper() {
      that.isDone = true;
    }
    setTimeout(helper, 100);
  }
  var obj = new f3();
  obj.isDone;  // Will return false.
  ... // Wait 100 ms and ask it again.
  obj.isDone;  // Should be true now.
```

I hope I didn't go too far off on a tangent with "this"; however, I know it
can be the source of a lot of pain so I wanted to bring it up if you run into
it.

Allow me to present the next gotcha. Consider the following.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(i);
    }, 100);
  }
```

If you run that code, you will see an alert that says "3" 3 times. It actually
won't do a count from 1 to 3. This is a common mistake with closures. The
reason is because you execute the for loop all the way through before you call
the callback in setTimeout. So when it's time for the anonymous function to
resolve what i is, it find out it's 3, each time.

You can read more about that at http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62 and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops:_A_common_mistake

Answer (score -2):

The reason why x and y are both visible inside helper() function is because you made them global for any function inside f1() by using var keyword. Had you defined both variables without var keyword, they wouldn't be visible inside helper() function.

Comment: Without var they will be declared as global (on window) and will be visible outside f1().